# Problem in M3G rendering in J2ME

Tags: java-me, rendering, cube, m3g

I have made 3 planes and positioned them in a way that they make a corner of cube. (For some reasons I don't want to make a cube object). The 3 planes have 3 different Texture2Ds with different images. The strange problem is when I render the 3 objects and start rotating the camera, in some perspectives some parts of these 3 planes don't get rendered. For example when I look straight at the corner a hole is created which is shaped as a triangle. This is the image of the problem in a netbeans emulator:
[alt text http://www.pegahan.com/m3g.jpg](http://www.pegahan.com/m3g.jpg) 
I put the red lines there so you can see the cube better.
The other strange thing is that the problem resolves when I set the scale of the objects to 0.5 or less.
By the way the camera is in its default position and the cube's center is at (0,0,0) and each plane has a width and height of 2.
Does anyone have any ideas why these objects have a conflict with each other and how could I resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

looks like classic case of "box bigger then camera far clipping plane" error :)

since I don't know anything about m3g I can just point you to google that.